# How to match either/or with Regex

Tags: regex

I apologise for the Regex question but..

I'm developing a regex expression for scraping Job titles.

The job Title will always be in the format:

Job title: Word1 Word2 (Optional Word3)

At the minute I currently have this:

```
Job Title: ([A-Z\w]+ [A-Z\w]+)|Job Title: ([A-Z\w]+ [A-Z\w]+ [A-Z\w]+)
```

I'm trying to get it to match job titles with either two or three words, and each side of the pipe character works individually (left side matches 2 word job titles, right side matchs 3 word job titles), however when I add the pipe character it only goes for the left half, matching 2 word job titles.

Does anybody have an idea what I'm doing wrong?

NB: I'm using [Regexper](https://regexper.com/#Job%20Title%3A%20(%5BA-Z%5Cw%5D%2B%20%5BA-Z%5Cw%5D%2B)%7CJob%20Title%3A%20(%5BA-Z%5Cw%5D%2B%20%5BA-Z%5Cw%5D%2B%20%5BA-Z%5Cw%5D%2B)) to visualise my expression, and it looks correct there.

Cheers.

Comment: Is the regex flavor ES5, or PCRE, or any other? What is the language you are using it in?

Comment: What comes after the second word? Another word? If so, how do you distinguish that from a third job-title-word? What I'm getting at is - if the line ends there, why not grab the rest of the line? I.e. `Job Title: (.*)$`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for that is that the left part can match the same substring (at the same position) what the right alternative can match, and the pattern is not anchored. You either need to anchor it, or swap the alternatives. Or use an optional group. Here is an enhanced version:

```
Job Title: ([A-Z]\w* [A-Z]\w*(?: [A-Z]\w*)?)
                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xW4gI0/1)

If you do not care if the initial letters are in lower- or uppercase, add the `/i` case-insensitive modifier (or the corresponding flag (like `re.I`, `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase`, etc.) depending on the regex flavor):

```
/Job Title: ([A-Z]\w* [A-Z]\w*(?: [A-Z]\w*)?)/i
```

Since the `[A-Z\w]+` makes little sense as `\w` matches `A-Z`, I advise to use `[A-Z]\w*` - an uppercase ASCII letter followed with zero or more alphanumeric/underscore characters.

The non-capturing group `(?: [A-Z]\w*)` is made optional (this part can be missing from the input) since it is quantified with `?` quantifier that means *one or zero occurrences*.

Comment: Try these on for size ;) `Professor of Archeology`, `Dean of Students`, `Queen of England`.

Comment: @ClasG: If you hint at the fact that the words do not have to be capitalized, then it is a simple fix - add a `/i` modifier: [`/Job Title: ([A-Z]\w* [A-Z]\w*(?: [A-Z]\w*)?)/i`](https://regex101.com/r/xW4gI0/9). I added a note about that to the answer.

Comment: Or simply remove the `[A-Z]`...?

Comment: If you remove `[A-Z]`, `Job Title: 12 34` will get matched. I do not know why OP used `[A-Z\w]`, I assumed the first character must be a letter.

Comment: I don't know if OP wants syntax checking... But I guess I'd go with `\S` allowing people to enter what they want... E.g. `Job Title: 2'nd Violin`.

Comment: Yes, for extracting anything that you do not know, `\S+` instead of `[A-Z]\w*` is best here.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I'm using the Apex language on the Salesforce platform, which uses a Java implementation of regex. This means the `/i modifier` is added like this: `(?i)Job Title: ([A-Z]\\w* [A-Z]\\w*(?: [A-Z]\\w*)?)`

Also, thanks for the `\S+` suggestion, I've implemented that instead. This is my first foray into regex.

Comment: Glad it helped. Actually, the point of interest was the optional group here anyway. Surely, in Java C strings backslashes before regex metacharacters must be doubled, and the inline modifiers are also my favorite way of introducing different modes to my patterns.

Answer (score 0):

How about that:

```
Job Title: ((?: *[A-Z]\w+){2,3})
```

See it in action [here](https://regex101.com/r/xW4gI0/7)

That way, if the number of words accepted changes at some point, you don't have much to change to adapt the solution.

You can add `$` at the end if you don't want to match the case where people enter more than 3 words: like [this](https://regex101.com/r/xW4gI0/8)